# How do I print page footer on last page ONLY

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, footer, ms-access-2016

I got to update an application for a client (MS Access 2016).

This one uses it for a lot of bills (many) and he wants to print the footer (with his total, etc) only on the last page ...

I understand it, no problem, but, after a day of work, i have no idea of how i can do it (properly).

I don't understand why microsoft doesn't include a propertie like  "footers -> only on last page" for their report.

If anyone can provide me a little help... it could be great

Comment: Use the Report Footer.

Comment: I tried, but this one is not on the bottom of the page (I'm sorry I didn't mention this point)

Answer (score 0):

In the Format or Print event you can set:

```
Me.<SectionNameConstant>.Visible = (Me.Page = Me.Pages)
```

I can't off the head remember the constant, sorry.